# Can I create a single user-specific link to a document?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, office365, documents, document-management

I want to sell a single online document to 30 people. The dilemma I'm facing is if one person pays, s/he can share the link to others and they might not buy again.

Is it possible I generate a non-transferable link to an online document that will be specific to a single user?

If not, what are other alternatives I can use to solve this challenge?

Answer (score 1):

### Not possible.

#### As soon as someone gets a copy of a file, they can share that file without even needing a link.

The only solution is make someone view something but use your own services which makes it a DRM kind of thing and is not very customer friendly.

Even then, if it is not properly protected, someone can rip it.

Also, keeping the protection running will cost money. It may be more expensive to keep the protection running with how much you sell, vs just selling it without protection and take for granted that someone shares the content with someone else.

At least, you can use a format that one can't easily alter, for example: word document or image, share it as pdf.

Comment: I added at least. Sharing a word doc is the source, pdf is one step ahead of keeping people from editing. The very basic people will not be able to edit.